# Emacs: reload from file for all buffers

Tags: emacs

If I want to reload from disk a file that is in a buffer, I can do `M-x revert-buffer`. Is there an equivalent command that will do this for all open buffers at once?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following simple function,

```
(defun my-revert-all ()
  (interactive)
  (dolist (buff (buffer-list))
    (ignore-errors                      ; ignore errors from buffers w/ no files
      (revert-buffer buff))))
```

which could be modified further to pass all the arguments similar to `revert-buffer`.